# Проверка полей на заполнение jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Есть следующий блок:

```
<div class="player">
    <input type="text" class="input_firstname player_input" name="player[][firstname]" placeholder="Введите имя">
    <input type="text" class="input_lastname player_input" name="player[][lastname]" placeholder="Введите фамилию">
    <input type="text" class="input_birthday player_input" name="player[][birthday]" placeholder="Введите дату рождения">
    <input type="text" class="input_passport player_input" name="player[][passport]" placeholder="Серия и номер паспорта">
    <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Как при вводе данных в какое-либо поле проверять остальные на заполнение?
По умолчанию `<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>` не отображается, необходимо его отобразить только после заполнения всех полей в блоке `player`.

Сразу скажу, таких блоков много, поэтому нужно использовать `this`. 
Также хотелось бы спросить, правильно ли сделано `name` у этих полей? В итоге получится массив `player`, где после индекса будут идти `firstname`, `lastname` и т.д.?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь могут помочь следующие функции:

- [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) — установка обработчика на событие изменения поля ввода.
- [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) — нахождение ближайшего элемента к данному.
- [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) — найти элементы в поддереве.
- [`show`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) — показывает элемент.

Таким образом, при каждом изменении полей ввода мы будем проверять, заполнены ли все поля текущего блока, если заполнены, то найдём с помощью функции `closest` элемент `<i>` и покажем его.

```
$('.player input').change(function() {
  let playerBlock = $(this).closest('.player');
  let emptyInputs = playerBlock.find('input:empty');
  if (emptyInputs.length === 0) {
    playerBlock.find('.fa.fa-check').show();
  }
});
```